# Do the edits count towards the Tag Badge?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-badges

Tag Badge:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki
>   answers to achieve this badge.

You gain reputation when:

> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2

My questions are:

1. Do accepted edits count towards a total score for the Tag Badge?
2. Is there any way to see a total score for each of my favorite tags?

Comment: `score` and `reputation` are not the same here. :-)

Answer (score 7):

> Do accepted edits count towards a total score for the Tag Badge?

Score means the difference between upvotes and downvotes (score = number of upvotes - number of downvotes). Edits don't come into it.

> Is there any way to see a total scores for each of my favorite tags?

Sure. Go to your [profile tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292321/aygul?tab=tags) and hover over the number to the left of a tag. A tooltip will give you all the details.

Answer (score -1):

Well, 'normally', your edits don't need acceptance since you've gotten that privilege. It follows that having edits go into effect does not say much. On the other hand, perhaps *rejected* edits should count *against* getting a tag badge... (:evil:)